# portable drive does not stop "vibration" even after safely ejecting out

Tags: hard-drive

I usually touch the portable hard drive with my bare fingers to make sure it's not vibrating anymore before actually unplugging the USB cables. Sometime even after I have safely ejected the drive in windows 10 but it never stops vibration. I can't even find the drive in device manager, but it's still vibrating, making me feel uncomfortable to take away its USB cables and stop it.

Is there anyway I can stop that? If I don't stop that, is there any harm to the hard drive

Answer (score 1):

### Conclusion

You can unplug the drive while it is vibrating, then you should wait for it to stop vibrating before you pick it up.

### Short Answer

> Is there anyway I can stop that?

You can send the bridge the command to put the drive in standby, which *might* make it spin down.

> is there any harm to the hard drive

You won't physically damage the drive by unplugging it while the platters are spinning and even when the heads are flying. Always wait for the platters to come to a rest before handling the drive after unplugging it.

### Long Answer

It depends on the USB<->SATA bridge interface chip whether or not it sends the proper command to the drive to enter standby when you eject it from Windows or send the bridge the standby command.

It also depends on the driver implementation, so be sure that if there are any drivers intended to be used with the portable disk, that you have them installed. Usually there are no drivers beyond the default ones provided by Windows.

As for unplugging the USB cord (which is also how it is powered I presume) while the heads are flying, this is usually and mostly harmless. A powerful magnet will park the heads once power is cut.

Older drives can sometimes be damaged this way, as the heads are heavier and the magnets larger causing a loud clicking sound when power is cut, but any drive built in the last 10-15 years should not have this issue.

As long as you unplug your hard drive and let the platters come to a rest before handling it, there will be no physical damage, even if you unplug it without ejecting it while writing/reading data. Modern drives are designed quite well and can safely withstand sudden power loss during any operation except a firmware flash. (always unmount/eject filesystems on disk before unplugging as data can be damaged, though physically the drive won't be).

### Directly sending standby command to disk

This program here is a port of `hdparm` for Windows. It can directly send the standby command to disks. This utility manipulates disk drives at a low level and should not be used for any reason by a novice or used on production systems as it has more than enough ability to **destroy data and the disk itself permanently** if misused.

Proceed with caution. This tool is not tested on any Windows version beyond Vista.
[hdparm-6.9-win32-bin.zip](http://axh.mbnet.fi/projects/hdparm-6.9-win32-bin.zip)

Alternatively you could boot linux, and using the native hdparm utility from Linux you can set powersaving parameters on the disk, which causes the disk to spin itself down after a set amount of time being idle. Ejecting the disk would essentially idle the disk and begin the timer for the spin-down.

The `hdparm` tool on linux is more powerful than on Windows, so use with caution.

Usage on Windows (unrelated parameters omitted):

```
hdparm.exe  [options] [device] ..

-B   set Advanced Power Management setting (1-255)
-S   set standby (spindown) timeout
-y   put IDE drive in standby mode
-Y   put IDE drive to sleep
```

Example:

```
hdparm.exe -B 255 \\.\PhysicalDrive1
hdparm.exe -Y \\.\D:
```

Comment: Thanks. However, as you said the command is operated at "low level" and should be handled with caution or otherwise permanent damage could be made. Do you mean ,as a conclusion, it's fine to just unplug it while it's like vibration and let it wait and it's OK for everything and we can ignore the command

Comment: The command can be sent safely, the tool however can do much more (such as reading/writing sectors directly, or reconfiguring hidden settings on drive (Linux only))

As a conclusion, yes you can unplug the drive while it is vibrarting, after which you should wait until it is done vibrating to handle it any further than unplugging it.

Updated answer.